# How do you center 3 divs in a row?

Tags: html, css, centering

I'm having trouble getting my 3 divs to center. They appear to be almost centered but there's still more white space on the right side than there is on the left. I'm including my html and css along with a link to the site.

http://alexrdzv2.herokuapp.com/index.html

Also, when I make the window larger, it gets even worse.

I should mention that the container it's wrapped in only has the following properties - width: 80%, margin: auto, and overflow: hidden. I have all the sections in my page wrapped inside this container but I know it's not the problem since I've tried doing it without it and the boxes still won't properly center.

```css
#boxes {
    min-height: 200px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#boxes .box {
    margin-top: 20px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 10px;
  }

#boxes .fab {
    padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<section id="boxes">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <i class="fab fa-html5 fa-3x"></i><i class="fab fa-css3-alt fa-3x"></i><i class="fab fa-js fa-3x"></i>
            <h1><a href="">Color Game</a></h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alkej cklvne alke.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <i class="fab fa-html5 fa-3x"></i><i class="fab fa-css3-alt fa-3x"></i><i class="fab fa-js fa-3x"></i>
            <h1><a href="">Color Game</a></h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo facere aut ipsum possimus.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <i class="fab fa-html5 fa-3x"></i><i class="fab fa-css3-alt fa-3x"></i><i class="fab fa-js fa-3x"></i>
            <h1><a href="">Color Game</a></h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo facere aut ipsum possimus..</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Try width 33%..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flexbox` CSS3 feature for center your boxes, for this you need to add below CSS in your `container` class.

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

#boxes {
    min-height: 200px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#boxes .box {
    margin-top: 20px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 10px;
  }

#boxes .fab {
    padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<section id="boxes">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <i class="fab fa-html5 fa-3x"></i><i class="fab fa-css3-alt fa-3x"></i><i class="fab fa-js fa-3x"></i>
            <h1><a href="">Color Game</a></h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alkej cklvne alke.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <i class="fab fa-html5 fa-3x"></i><i class="fab fa-css3-alt fa-3x"></i><i class="fab fa-js fa-3x"></i>
            <h1><a href="">Color Game</a></h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo facere aut ipsum possimus.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <i class="fab fa-html5 fa-3x"></i><i class="fab fa-css3-alt fa-3x"></i><i class="fab fa-js fa-3x"></i>
            <h1><a href="">Color Game</a></h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo facere aut ipsum possimus..</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be accomplished using Bootstrap very easily if you're willing to use the library. You can simply add the row class to the container div, and add col-md-3 to each div element. Rows in bootstrap have a width of 12 'units', so col-md-3 is a column with a third of the available width.

```
<section id="boxes">
    <div class="container row">
        <div class="box col-md-3">
            <i class="fab fa-html5 fa-3x"></i><i class="fab fa-css3-alt fa-3x"></i><i class="fab fa-js fa-3x"></i>
            <h1><a href="">Color Game</a></h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alkej cklvne alke.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box col-md-3">
            <i class="fab fa-html5 fa-3x"></i><i class="fab fa-css3-alt fa-3x"></i><i class="fab fa-js fa-3x"></i>
            <h1><a href="">Color Game</a></h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo facere aut ipsum possimus.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box col-md-3">
            <i class="fab fa-html5 fa-3x"></i><i class="fab fa-css3-alt fa-3x"></i><i class="fab fa-js fa-3x"></i>
            <h1><a href="">Color Game</a></h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo facere aut ipsum possimus..</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

further documentation on this topic in bootstrap can be found here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

downloadable files for bootstrap can be found here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/download/

Although Bootstrap is not the only solution, it is the one I would prefer to use.

Comment: you can easily do with flexbox so why you want to use bootstrap GRID on this and for kind information bootstrap grid depend on flexbox, so in all of the end grid apply my css mentioned below

Comment: you're right, your answer is simpler and clearly the optimal solution here. I'm just providing an alternative :)